# Understanding function pointers and reference

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Consider the following types:

```
template <class R, class... Args> using type0 = R(Args...);
template <class R, class... Args> using type1 = R(*)(Args...);
template <class R, class... Args> using type2 = R(&)(Args...);
template <class R, class C, class... Args> using type3 = R(C::*)(Args...);
template <class R, class C, class... Args> using type4 = R(C::&)(Args...);
// Any other existing syntax? R(&&)(Args...)? R(const*)(Args...)? R()(Args..)?
```

What types actually exist? What is the difference between `type0`, `type1`, `type2`, `type3`, `type4`? What does the middle parenthesis mean? Are they all function pointers? Where could I find an exhaustive documentation about this syntax, because it is very unclear to me?

Comment: C doesn't have templates.

Comment: @owacoder tag changed

Comment: To answer 'what's the difference': `typo0` is a function, `type1` is a pointer to a function, `type2` is a reference to a function, `type3` is a pointer to a member function, `type4` is a reference to a a member function, unless I'm mistaken. `R(const*)(Args...)` is not valid, as functions can not 'change'.

Comment: For all possible cases, you could reference [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types instantiated via alias templates `type0` through `type3` all exist. You can't have objects of a function type, though, i.e., there are no instances of the types instantiated via the alias template `type0`.

There is no "reference to member"-type, i.e., I don't think `type4` works

The types are reasonably easy to understand:

1. `R(Args...)` is a function *value* type (return `R` and taking `Args...` as arguments). Essentially, that's the type a function has. C++ doesn't allow values of this type.
2. `R(*)(Args...)` is a function *pointer* type. The parenthesis around the `*` (and if there is a name, the name as in `(*name)`) are needed to disambiguate whether the `*` binds to the return type `R` (the default) or the function type (when there are parenthesis). When you want to pass a function somewhere, you don't use a function value but a function pointer. You can call a function through a function pointer. You can think of a function pointer to be the address where the function implementation lives although there is no guarantee that this is also how it is implemented.
3. `R(&)(Args...)` is a function *reference* type. The relation between function pointers and function reference is the same as that between pointer and reference: you'll get a function reference if you dereference a function pointer.
4. `R(C::*)(Args...)` is a member function pointer type. That is essentially a handle for a member function. These are more like indices into lists of member functions but identify a member function. With an object `o` and a member function pointer `mem` you can call the member function using something like `(o.*mem)(args...)`. If the member function used to initialize the pointer to member is `virtual` dynamic dispatch will happen (I don't think there is a way to prevent dynamic dispatch when calling though a member function pointer).

In addition to those function declarations listed the member function pointer type can have `const`/`volatile` and/or ref-qualification and there are variable argument versions of the function type. That is, there are also

- pointer to `const` members:

  ```
  template <class R, class C, class... Args>
  using mem_const = R(C::*)(Args...) const`
  ```
- pointer to `volatile` members:

  ```
  template <class R, class C, class... Args>
  using mem_volatile =  R(C::*)(Args...) volatile
  ```
- pointer to `const volatile` members:

  ```
  template <class R, class C, class... Args>
  using mem_const_volatile =  R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile
  ```
- pointer to lvalue qualified members:

  ```
  template <class R, class C, class... Args>
  using mem_lvalue =  R(C::*)(Args...) &;
  ```
- pointer to rvalue qualified members:

  ```
  template <class R, class C, class... Args>
  using mem_rvalue =  R(C::*)(Args...) &&;
  ```
- all combinations of `const`/`volatile` and lvalue/rvalue qualification.
- variable argument list versions of function types (the `......` can alternatively also be written as a `... ...` or `..., ...`):

  ```
  template <class R, class... Args>
  using varargs = R(Args......);
  ```
- All function pointer, reference, and member function pointer types with a trailing variable argument list.

I think this is [currently] a reasonably exhaustive list of functions and member-functions, their qualified version, and their pointer/reference versions. With C++17 also adding exception specifications to the mix, there will also be a `noexcept(true)` version (in addition to the default `noexcept(false)` one.